# is it possible to proxy secure applications?

Tags: 14.04, server, proxy, https

Internet ---------- Proxy Server (network Edge)

```
                  |        |        |
                  |        |        |
                GitLab   App 2     App3
```

So I have gitlab installed on a VM in my internal network and I want to proxy it securely to the internet but so far my efforts have been fruitless, is what I'm trying to do possible or do I need to buy a cheap VPS?

P.S I have work I can show.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution would be to use NAT at the network edge.  However, this is not a proxy solution.  A firewall could route some traffic via NAT, and route other traffic to a transparent proxy.

Proxy aware applications can as for a `CONNECT` which allow them to connect through the proxy.  The proxy will transfer data without looking inside.  Normally, it will log the connection endpoint.

The proxy can transparently accept the connection, and then proxy it much likely a non-transparent proxy. There can be issues with creating the connections.  It is not possible to handle all cases.  The proxy flows begin before the encryption has been negotiated, so there is no man-in-the-middle vulnerability.

The proxy can provide a key for the target site, and perform a man-in-the-middle attack.  If you trust the proxy, this may be acceptable for lower risk connections.  For connections to Banks and other connections requiring higher levels of security, the proxy can act transparently as described above.  This would be a relatively transparent proxy, but provides a ready made place for a man-in-the-middle attack.